# Write text to a .CS file just before end of the two braces

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, file-io

I have a requirement, in it I have to do the following things:

1. Generate code dynamically
2. Write the code into an existing .cs file
3. I have to add the code just before the last two braces of the class file.

For e.g. the class file is :

```
namespace Stackoverflow
{
    public class AskQuestion
    {
        public void Ask()
        {
        }

    //Add the generated code here.
    }
}
```

I tried following code : 
Created a class FindBraceLocation

```
namespace DBInfo.Class
{
    public class FindBraceLocation
    {
        private int _bracePositionInLine;
        private int _noOfBraceFound;
        private int _lineNoIndex;
        private readonly string[] _fs;

        public int LineNoIndex
        {
            get { return _lineNoIndex; }
            set { _lineNoIndex = value; }
        }

        public int BracePositionInLine
        {
            get { return _bracePositionInLine; }
            set { _bracePositionInLine = value; }
        }

        public int NoOfBraceFound
        {
            get { return _noOfBraceFound; }
            set { _noOfBraceFound = value; }
        }

        public FindBraceLocation(string[] allLines)
        {
            _bracePositionInLine = -1;
            _noOfBraceFound = 0;
            _lineNoIndex = 0;
            _fs = allLines;
        }

        public void SearchFileStringIndex()
        {
            int noOfLines = _fs.Length;
            string line;
            int lineCounter;
            int pos2 = -1;

            for (lineCounter = noOfLines - 1; lineCounter >= 0; lineCounter--)
            {
                line = _fs[lineCounter];
                if (line.Trim().Length == 0)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                pos2 = FindIndexOfBrace(line);
                if (pos2 != -1)
                    break;
            }

            _lineNoIndex = lineCounter;
            _bracePositionInLine = pos2;
        }

        public int FindIndexOfBrace(string line)
        {
            //int braceNo = _noOfBraceFound;

            for (int counter = line.Length - 1; counter >= 0; counter--)
            {
                if (line[counter] == '}' && (++_noOfBraceFound == 2))
                {
                    return counter;
                }
            }
            return -1;
        }
    }

}
```

And used the following method to write it into a file :

```
        protected void WriteToExistingGeneratedFile(string strInfo, string strPath)
        {
            string[] allLines = File.ReadAllLines(strPath);
            FindBraceLocation fp = new FindBraceLocation(allLines);
            fp.SearchFileStringIndex();
            string lineForInsertion = allLines[fp.LineNoIndex];
            string tempLine = lineForInsertion.Substring(0, fp.BracePositionInLine) + "\n" + strInfo + "\n" + lineForInsertion.Substring(fp.BracePositionInLine);
            allLines[fp.LineNoIndex] = tempLine;
            File.WriteAllLines(strPath, allLines);

        }
```

Comment: So what is your question? Do you want someone to do it for you?

Comment: Show your work.  What have you tried already?

Comment: Did you make any effort to accompplish this or just decide to post the question on here?

Comment: I did try...This is taking a lot of time to write, is there any other way to do this.

Comment: Sounds like a case for CodeDOM to me.

Comment: @UserM I think your question could be improved by clarifying exactly what you want. You should edit your post to detail what is/isn't working.

Comment: downvote removed, thanks for showing an.......  interesting... way to tackle this requirement

Comment: @UserM The fact that it's taking you a while doesn't mean it's appropriate to get other people to do the work for you...

Comment: So what needs to be done in that case? Sorry I have no idea about CodeDom

Comment: I just want an optimized way to write the code, the code is working but it's just taking a lot of time.

Comment: Downvote removed, now that OP has added the code

Answer (score 8):

Instead of modifying the existing file, dynamically generate a second file and [use the `partial` keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx) to add new members to the class.

*Static file:*

```
namespace Stackoverflow
{
    public partial class AskQuestion
    {
        public void Ask()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

*Generated file:*

```
namespace Stackoverflow
{
    partial class AskQuestion
    {
        // Dynamically generated methods and properties
    }
}
```

Comment: The need for this functionality is that we have couple of methods to be added into a file dynamically and we are not sure how many, It may scale upto even 30-35 methods...

Comment: This is, by far, a better way to do it

Comment: @UserM: Then figure out what these 30-35 methods are and write all of them at the same time to the file. Repeatedly appending more methods to a file is not a good idea.

Comment: @UserM I'd like to hear more about the motivation behind this requirement. It seems bizarre, I wonder if it could be achieved through inheritance or extension methods or some other means?

Comment: I don't see how the number of "injected" methods matter.

Comment: @Alan I am creating a tool to create structs for the stored procedures present in our database. There are more than 400 SPs. So on click, the structs should be created for the selected SP.

Comment: @Steiner we'll be using this tool to generate structs and it's not necessary to do that at once. So everytime if we do it it'll create a new file.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a stream reader you can use the normal string functions on it. Something like this would work:

```
System.IO.StreamReader myFile =
new System.IO.StreamReader("c:\\test.cs");
string myString = myFile.ReadToEnd();

// This will error if there are not at least 2 parentheses.
string UpToLastParan = myString.Text.Substring(0, myString.LastIndexOf("}"));
int SecondToLast = UpToLastParan.LastIndexOf("}");
string UpToSecondToLastParan = myString.Substring(0, SecondToLast);
string CorrectedString = UpToSecondToLastParan + "Your Code Here" + myString.Substring(SecondToLast, myString.Length - SecondToLast);

// Write back to file.
```